# PDF Slides Rotating when Pages per Sheet Value is Changed (Chrome/Windows)

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, pdf, printing

First off, I'm sorry if this is not the proper forum for this question, but I am not sure where else to go. Basically, I am trying to print off lecture slides from a PDF one of my professors gives to us before our classes. Every class I have done this for had every page dedicated to a single slide, and so I would change the number of pages per sheet to 6 to save paper. I have never had a problem with it before this class, and it seems specific to this professors' lecture slides.

Normally, the pages print as follows (portrait):

1 2

3 4

5 6

But when I try to print this professors' slides, each one rotates 90 degrees counterclockwise, printing as follows (landscape):

5 3 1

6 4 2

This is a pretty big inconvenience for me, as I am not comfortable with reading right to left. Portrait is preferable to landscape, but I would take being able to read from left to right over anything else.

I would also like to state that I have tried preemptively rotating all of the slides in the PDF with DocHub, and the problem persisted. Further, I am using Windows 10 and my standard PDF viewer is just Google Chrome. I don't know if any of this is relevant to my issue, but that's how it is.

Let me know if you would need a copy or example of the strangely-behaving slides to offer help, any of which would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the problem can be resolved easily using PDF software like Acrobat;because of limited settings in browsers - i will suggest you to use those software; Also you can try - importing PDF file to word then print it {word has option to change page orders}

Comment: @Madhubala Opening in Word did not work entirely because it makes the whole document editable, moving pictures to new slides and turning it into a big mess; it did fix the printing order problem, but the introduction of new problems is not worth it. And I cannot afford Acrobat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I figured out an answer: Adobe's free PDF to PPT converter [here](https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/pdf-to-ppt.html). I'm still not quite sure what the problem was, but now the pages can be printed properly.